How can I renumber the sections and remove the chapter prefix?
How can I renumber the sections in each chapter to look like this:
Chapter 1
1. (First section)

2. (Second section) 

Chapter 2 
1. (First section)

2. (Second section) 

It appears in my file
Chapter 1
1.1 (First section)

1.2 (Second section) 

Chapter 2 

2.1 (First section)

2.2 (Second section) 

as per the default layout with the chapter prefix.

Related: Continuous v. per-chapter/section numbering of figures, tables, and other document elements

This is as simple as redefining how the section counter is represented. By default, it has the following definition:
\renewcommand \thesection {\thechapter.\@arabic\c@section}

You'll find these definitions in the class files that have chapters in them (like book and report). So, the above implies a prefix of \thechapter (however that is defined). You can redefine it and remove that prefix:
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

Note though that this approach may make things difficult to reference properly, as the chapter context is lost. For example, does a reference to section 2 in chapter 2 refer to the section in that chapter, or perhaps another chapter.

For adding a dot after the section number, you can update \@seccntformat:
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@seccntformat}[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname.\quad}
\makeatother

Again, the default (defined in latex.ltx) just doesn't have the . preceding the \quad in its definition.
If you only want this for sections and not subsections, say, see \@seccntformat only for section.

Thanks, it worked perfectly. I knew it was something simple, but I didn't know how to do it. It cost!
